# Revenge downvotes, not invalidated after two accepted flags

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

Last Wednesday, I left a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485817/get-elevation-of-route-in-google-maps). Then the OP (who thought I was the one who had downvoted&voted for close) revenge downvoted three of my answers/questions and left a non-constructive/rude comments against each of them (i.e. something like "This is the worst answer for any questions on SO.").

I waited until the other day and realised the serial vote detector can't get this as A. votes are on both questions&answers and B. voted in 2 minutes rather than 1.

> [image: Revenge downvotes]

So I flagged one of the comments and described the situation and asked for votes revert, which got accepted and all three comments got removed.

> [image: Flag1]

As all the revenge votes are still there, I waited a bit more and raised another flag against the question I had commented on, described the situation again and specifically asked for the moderator to revert the votes. This again got accepted, and I was assured that those votes will be invalidated.

> [image: Flag2]

But the votes are still there as of today, what else should I do?

Comment: Just to be patient. The SE team time is limited and they have to prioritise the work. Invalidating three votes that aren't causing you anything like a question/answer ban and that doesn't look like it's part of ongoing behaviour isn't really that big a priority given other things that need their attention I'm afraid. It'll be in their queue and will be looked at - again - you'll just need to not worry about it and be patient for a while longer.

Comment: @JonClements worth noting that this may take up to several months (that's my experience)

Comment: @gnat, Wow, thanks! I was a bit too optimistic then...

Comment: @Bolu that's perhaps an extreme example - but unless it's a severe case of voting abuse they can take a while...

Comment: If you're not being revenge voted upon, you're not doing StackOverflow correctly. Cherish those votes. Let the hate flow through you.

Comment: SO is pathway to many abilities... some consider to be... unnatural

Comment: Revenge vote them back! VOTE WAR!

Comment: @GillBates Uh... How do I downvote a comment? ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The art of spotting sarcasm through written words is a precious one.

Comment: @GillBates Exactly! It is for the benefit of these not endowed with the precious art of spotting sarcasm that I would downvote your comment on revenge voting them back :-)

Comment: Just for the record, got the "Voting corrected" yesterday :)