# Show anonymized but complete voting information to moderators

Tags: discussion, feature-request, serial-voting, moderator-abilities

Despite trying to "be nice", commenting instead of downvoting and explaining when I hammer-close a question with a duplicate, (and *not* commenting when downvoting/deleting most of the time & in review :)), I managed to get serial-downvoted a few times.

2 times it was a massive downvote, and it was reverted the next days. 2 other times, it was a more subtle [under-the-radar downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316567/serial-downvoting-under-the-radar?s=1%7C1.7668). Both times, the offender chose 3 or 4 of my top-rated questions and downvoted them.

My [top-rated questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre?tab=questions) (link *not* provided for voting!) are python questions, unrelated to each other. So clearly serial downvoting unless 3 people visit my profile at the same time, and choose 3 different questions (on the top list) to downvote upon :)

What happened [the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511517/how-to-disable-this-particular-warning) is similar to [Revenge downvotes, not invalidated after two accepted flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334798/revenge-downvotes-not-invalidated-after-two-accepted-flags), so the pattern is common, and the guy never got reversal. My second flag is pending with a (very nice) comment from a moderator

> Forwarded to the CM team for further investigation. It does look like a series to me, but we can't make promises on them being reverted.

(<strike>no doubt that I'll never see those votes reverted...</strike> EDIT: got them reverted after 1 week, many thanks to the mods! in the meanwhile, got other downvotes on other questions... flag pending. sigh.)

So the moderator *knows* that it's serial downvoting but cannot prove it, and has to escalate to SO employees, with more powerful rights, but also powerless against the bulk of requests like that.

Same goes for serial upvoting (which is less detrimental for individuals, but more harmful for the site)

The moderators *cannot know* who voted, let's keep it that way but let's provide them with some new tools:

- showing voters under a generated pseudo. Each voter has the same pseudo (like in Swiss bank anonymous accounts, the ones who have such an account know what I mean:)), which could change every x months to avoid someone figuring the names out
- make them able to manually reverse the votes when they're sure, and/or escalate to SO employees if action is needed (voting ring, sock puppets)

Say that I was serial-downvoted by "John" (but we don't know that yet). I flag my post and the moderator sees that "bozo122435" (generated pseudo for "John") downvoted 3 of my posts: now the mod knows that the same user voted on my posts: no need for rocket science to prove that it's serial downvoting.

That would also allow to detect serial upvoting ("bozo423526" appears in all my top answers) and voting rings (3 distinct pseudos appear to have upvoted the same user 30 times in a short period of time)

So after that, SO employees would remain the only ones knowing who voted (we don't care about the names anyway), but moderators would know for sure when serial voting occurs when checking a flagged post, would be autonomous to handle "small" irregularities, and could present a more detailled analysis to the SO employees for them to take punitive measures.

I fear that this feature is too complicated/costly to implement. Just in case no-one ever had that idea, and it's super-easy to do, worth a shot...

Comment: The only certian way to avoid serial downvoting on questions is to not ask any.  The more questions you have, the larger the target.  I've only asked 5 questions and, because of 'stealth serial downvoting', I will have to be absolutely desperate to ever ask another:(

Comment: @MartinJames that's sad, but you may be right. The "big" downvoting I was subject to were on _answers_ though. As if he guy _knew_ that they were going to be reversed, or if the guy didn't even know that you lose 1 rep on answers DV :) And if I'm a 125 rep user, I can downvote all questions I want, as long as I want...

Comment: This wouldn't close the feedback loop.  Only CMs and people that have close access to the internals would be able to do anything about this anyway.  Realistically speaking, the only time that CMs would get involved would be if either the script was too lenient or too aggressive in the efforts to roll back.

Comment: If one downvoted several of your answers, then check which user might correlate with the time of the votes (due to a comment, one of your downvotes or close vote on one of their question), note their reputation and check if it increases the amount of votes which were reverted. You might be able to identify the voter by that.

Comment: @Makoto I suppose that the script is "optimistic": it cannot afford to revert legitimate votes. So only human eye can decide.

Comment: @Tom:  The point of the whole "votes are anonymous" thing is for *us* to ***not*** identify the voter.  We really, really don't need *more* pitchforks and witch hunts over someone not voting fairly.  We *already* have scripts for that.

Comment: @Tom: moreover, downvoting questions doesn't cost rep, so your trick doesn't work. And as I said, I don't care about identifying the voter (for the first case I'm mentionning, I know almost for sure: after telling him that his question was a duplicate (which he didn't took too well), I answered his question and never got any comment or upvote, even by pinging him a few weeks after. I don't care: I want to kill serial voting on SO.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Your first comment said your answers were  targeted (as well), hence my comment :).

Comment: @Tom: even better: check the rep of the guy & his latest Q&A, delete your answers (for now) and check the guy rep the day after (undelete your answers after that!). But most of the time, the guy you're suspecting isn't the one (that would be too easy)

Comment: @Makoto That depends on what the downvote victim does. If they post the results on meta to notify others, then yes, we don't need that, but if they make a mental note to never comment a downvote on the perpetrators posts again, then that's fine for me.

Comment: For instance I know Makoto downvoted this very post and I'm not mad against him :) I just hope he's wrong and that my feature is doable :)

Comment: @Tom I wouldn't push it to downvoting (that would be revenge downvoting) But I often take mental notes to never upvote some people :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  This feature request is not doing *anything* beneficial to stop serial voting or address the issue at all.  **We already have scripts that handle the vast majority of these anomalies.**  By policy, only Stack Overflow employees may see fine-grained details about accounts who have and haven't been serial voting, to prevent a mob from going after them (for starters), and to prevent false accusations and genuine bad blood.  We **do not** need community moderators handling this aspect.  Delegating to actual employees is sufficient.

Comment: @Makoto: ok, but they'll have to hire a few more :)

Comment: By all means if you think that the script hasn't been thorough in it work, feel encouraged to report that on Meta, but absolutely do *not* insinuate that any one user has been serial voting against you for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: @Makoto users figured out that the script has a threshold. Downvoting 3 questions in a few seconds isn't detected (and it's expected, I won't post a bug report on that). The script expects that the downvoter/upvoter is "greedy" and votes on 10 questions/answers. Like that it works.

Comment: @Tom:  Perhaps I *did* mean to tag the OP.  For a moment there I had interpreted your comment as something else.

Comment: @Makoto when one of your scripts (is that you who track down serial upvoters?if so good work) detects some anomaly, you have to flag them, then a moderator takes over, and escalates to an SO employee. Inefficient like hell if you ask me (no offence)

Comment: @Makoto Ok, no worries (I deleted the comment asking you about that).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Two things:  I'm not an employee, and given that I've been around for a while, for all of the noise about serial voting, I've seldom seen it be an issue which demanded change.  There have been a handful of cases in which the script was a bit conservative on its rollback, and that's when CMs have had to step in to address it, but just speaking as a Meta-hound, not really seeing any rationale to shift a relatively well-working system into something new.

Comment: @Makoto I trust your seniority here. And I know SO mechanics are delicately tuned (that's why this request doesn't ask to radically change the way the site works, because it's OK). So you're recommending to flag the post again to death ? maybe I'm impatient and I should let the CM (are those SO employees) do their job.

Comment: No.  I'm recommending that you wait for the script to do its job (it runs every night at about 2AM GMT).  There's no reason to raise alarms or anything like that.

Comment: @Makoto the downvotes occured 2 days ago and still not reversed. So the script didn't spot that. I know that I have to wait before flagging from my first downvote attack (which was reversed).

Comment: We do get to see names when there is a pattern. It's just that in your case, it was too limited to show in our tools. At that point you do need a CM to look at the whole; an anonymised view would be way too noisy anyway; on your account alone there are 100 entries of patterns of incoming votes, all of them innocent (as you've written plenty of answers by now); if we added anonymous micro-patterns there it'd just not be parsable anymore.

Comment: Next, I've seen plenty of smaller patterns, the ones that don't show up in the tooling for us moderators, get reverted automatically. I'm more than fine with sending the exceptions to the CMs. They really don't happen all *that* often.

Comment: To extend on what @Martijn Pieters said, this would especially be a problem with accounts with very high amounts of rep, as even with the current limits the voting history of a > 100k user can take a *long* time to load. Add to that *all* votes the user has ever cast or received and we just might have to paginate them, integrate search, etc. I'd imagine that'd take quite a bit of rearchitecturing, especially to implement search. In short, I think this would be nice to have, but I'm not sure how technically feasible it would be.

Comment: thanks Martjin & @BoltClock for your comments which make sense. Good to know that it's "nice to have", even if I strongly suspected that it was difficult. Well, who knows, maybe a part of another future evolution?

Comment: Pardon me if I am asking something everyone already knows, but can we hide the name of the gold badge user from anyone except the mods and other gold badge bearers? Granted OP might not be able to reply to them in comments, but there could be many solutions to that problem. I am supposing a large number of these downvotes come from the disgruntled OP's who don't like their questions downvoted or closed!

Comment: can a single person really do enough harm to a 55K user even worth spending the time to write this question much less trying to prove it to reverse it?

Comment: Also, can we post a hash of a set of parameters that map directly to the browsing session of a user, but it wouldn't be possible to trace the user back from that hash. Something like, hash(User ID + IP Address + Browser). Let the Mods see this hash against every vote. If they see the same hash against five consecutive votes, they know that it is the same user. The voting still remains anonymous as the hash will be different in a different session of the user. Does that make sense?

Comment: makes sense to me. But that's not up to me to decide or to implement it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson it's not about rep. I agree with you on that point. But if I "cross" 40 users dumb enough to downvote 2 or 3 of my questions, my questions will have a 0 score. _That_ is harmful because it would be like noone voted for them, so they won't stand out in searches, and the content will be less read (and the answers content too)

Comment: Also, what about those to whom the rep does matter?  Maybe they're just got enough rep to do some moderation, and then some deadbeat poster rips it away:(

Comment: @NisargShah I wouldn't hide the name of a gold badge user. OP or other users _must_ know who closed the issue. But the gold badge user doesn't have to close without a comment. See my post about this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352439/should-we-add-more-explanation-when-closing-as-duplicate

Comment: If you start to show anonymous names to moderators for votes, why not showing the same to all users? Like that, you would know if that three downvotes are from a same person or not without asking a mod.

Comment: @Cœur thanks for your support, but I don't think that would be wise. First, it would change the way the site appears to the public (we generally don't need to see who/which pattern was used to vote), and second, it would be easier to actually _know_ who downvoted (by analyzing many posts & votes & users commenting/posting). This possibility is reduced with just the mods, who are responsible and impartial.

Comment: FYI, my first mini-serial voting flagging resulted in vote-reversal. Thanks to the mods & CM/SE guys. The system works okay. It's just that some internal changes like what I'm proposing could speed up processing in terms of workload for the mods/CMs. Too bad we cannot thank the mod processing our flag (we don't even know who he/she is even if it's Martjin, I know it :))

Comment: From my point of view duplicate closing will always get some stupid revenge votes now and then but remember you are doing a great service for SO and future users and I really hope that one day SE will give you a few rep, Shog9 in a video talked about rep if for duplicate closing (even if only related to accepted duplicated by OP) and yes we would need something like that, since you are actually providing the solution

Comment: @PetterFriberg yeah that's sad. Maybe giving some rep for the closer would have a pervert effect: I'm closing as soon as I can with a not-that-related answer to get the rep, then I have time to search for the proper dupe. Or users would have to vote for the duplicate selection. Complex (I tried to ask such a thing here but got bashed). In the meantime, try to be nice & explain when flagging as duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352439/should-we-add-more-explanation-when-closing-as-duplicate?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: meeh not sure if few points 1-2 I don't think so, it would just fixed the revenge voting problem and give a thanks for providing answer.

Comment: @PetterFriberg could be limited to 10 points awarded like this per day, yes. But that doesn't make up for the vote count on questions which were revengefully downvoted (I've got 56k rep, I'm not after each rep point, but downvotes still affect me & my contributions). I closed dozens of questions as duplicates (single-handed, some call me "the king of dupehammer", but actually it's vaultah :)) and only got rarely revenge downvoted (if downvoted: flag and get your rep back after a few days/weeks in most of the cases)

Comment: Yeah maybe a nice feature, if you duplicate close that user can't down vote your for 24 hours ;), I  have seen a lot of that ugly stuff and it's really sad the doing such an important and useful task as closing duplicates is not appreciated.

Comment: :) the most vicious ones would use their agenda to remember to downvote the next day. I did that (for upvoting someone when I ran out of votes) :)

Answer (score 42):

There are probably ways that this could be implemented without violating anyone's privacy. However, there would be no real advantage to taking the time to implement it.

Moderators already *do* see a great deal of information about targeted voting patterns. We intentionally don't disclose the nature and amount of information accessible to us because that would facilitate gaming (people operating just below the threshold to avoid appearing on our radar).

The only thing we *don't* see is vote histories that are too small to meet that secret threshold, and there's a reason we don't see this information: it would be far too noisy if we did.

Active, high-reputation users get a crap-ton of votes, the vast majority of which are completely legitimate and do not need to be investigated. If we saw everyone who cast votes on two of Jon Skeet's answers, we would never be able to load that page or investigate any *actual* cases of vote fraud. The signal-to-noise ratio would simply be too low.

In the handful of cases where there is reason to suspect vote fraud, but the current moderator tools don't show us the required information, we can simply escalate the matter to one of the community managers, who have access to *complete* voting information and can thus perform a more thorough investigation. Their view doesn't even have to be anonymized, making it much easier for them to see patterns and respond appropriately.

At this point, there really aren't that many exceptional cases that need to be escalated to the community managers. And when there get to be so many that the CMs are overwhelmed, they'll campaign internally for the implementation of this feature (or something equivalent, like [a fine-tuning of the automatic vote reversal script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355999)), to ease the burden on themselves. Until that time, I don't see any reason to undertake a drastic redesign or any of its associated costs.

There are a *lot* of other features I'd rather the developers work on instead, with much more substantial benefits to the site at large.

Honestly, my response to this feature request was just to groan. Another user on Meta complaining about downvotes? Only one plot twist this time: it's a user with >10k reputation. So, you got a couple of downvotes. Big whoop. I anxiously await the downvotes on this answer.

Comment: Using reverse psychology to garner upvotes by expecting downvotes... smart.

Comment: I got some mini-revenge (2 or 3 downvotes simultaneously on unrelated well-written questions) on specific questions (score was 0 or 1, now it's -1 or 0). It has greatly impacted the visibility of those questions. What should I do?

Comment: It's not so much OP has gotten a downvote, it's that their actions in keeping the community clean by using the tools available to them has resulted in revenge essentially. The only revenge available to people here. While a downvote or two would hardly bother most, I feel there'd be additional frustration if they were occurring because OP is trying to help the community.

Comment: @Tas Neither you nor the OP has any idea *who* downvoted his questions, and thus there is no way to reasonably conclude it had any connection to actions taken in keeping the community clean.

Comment: @CodyGray fun (?) fact: I got (probably) serial downvoted on 3 questions today again (last time was last week). Is this the meta-effect for this post? I don't know. The good thing? when this clown will have downvoted all my posts, he would have to set up another account to downvote me again ;)

Comment: @CodyGray I don't care about the rep, I could regain it by "forgetting" to flag as duplicate and answer instead (that I'm not doing) or more seriously answering one or 2 good questions (bad day for me is around 100 rep). I care about the impact of the questions. Legit downvotes are ok by me. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to answer properly, even if I don't fully agree (but I never was a mod before so I may be missing some hindsight)

Comment: "I anxiously await the downvotes on this answer." Meta doesn't count :-P

Comment: I downvoted this answer to show agreement, as obviously everyone else is doing the same in the opposite direction.

Comment: When Cody says downvote, one simply has to downvote

Comment: @CodyGray  At what point should I bother complaining about revenge downvotes?  I've had it rarely happen to me, but today I've gotten two unrelated old posts downvoted within the same time period in the same situation Cœur's, where it wasn't the rep that mattered, but the visibility of the posts.

Comment: The danger here is assuming that all downvotes are "revenge" downvotes. How do you know those two downvotes weren't totally legitimate, @snb?And what is it that would make them illegitimate? If they were cast by the same user? If it was targeted voting, why didn't they go on to downvote other posts of yours? Why did they stop at those? Maybe they know something about the quality/accuracy of those posts that you are missing. That would make them legitimate votes.

Comment: @CodyGray Then why wouldn't they tell me?   Now I'm stuck with downvotes and reduce visibility w/ no way to know what I did wrong, under seemingly unscrupulous circumstances.   To avoid getting caught by the system + to maximize damage they would downvote posts with 0 counts and old posts, effectively destroying the hope that those questions ever see the light of day and get a proper answer.  Seriously what exactly am I supposed to do with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377656/radius-range-based-search-using-a-ball-tree) to make it acceptable? There's no feedback at all.

Comment: The downvote *is* the feedback, @snb. They wouldn't tell you anything because there's nothing they need to tell you. Users are *explicitly discouraged* from explaining their downvotes. Look to the tooltip on the downvote arrow for guidance.